# Understanding the solution of the problem from book Kaczor ,Nowak 1.1.8

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

[image]

Here I cannot understand the 2nd part proof given in the ans from the book of W.J.Kaczor and M.T.Nowak book volume 3 can anyone help me to understand that or any other equivalent proof.

Comment: Can you explain the symbols, expressions please

Comment: @psl2z Which symbol?

Comment: What is $\mathcal{R}(\alpha)$? What is $\mu(P)$? What is $S(P,f,\alpha)$? What is $P$?

Comment: @the_candyman P is a partition and the function is Riemann integrable

Comment: By "2nd part proof", do you mean the proof that $\ \lim_\limits{\mu(P)\rightarrow0}S(P,f,\alpha)\ $ doesn't exist?

Comment: A Riemann-Stieltjes sum $S(P,f,\alpha) = \sum_{k=1}^m f(t_k)[\alpha(x_k) - \alpha(x_{k-1}]$ depends on the choice for tags $t_k \in [x_{k-1},x_k]$.  They want you to show that there is a sequence of partitions $(P_n)$ such that $\mu(P_n) \to 0$ but the limit of $S(P_n,f,\alpha)$ may not exist independently of how the tags are chosen. Hint: Use $P_n =(-1,-\frac{n-1}{n}, \ldots, - \frac{2}{n},- \frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}, \frac{2}{n}, \ldots, \frac{n-1}{n},1)$. where $\mu(P_n) = 2/n \to 0$.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera yes

Comment: @RRL yes actually I confused that I choose the tag near 0 can you clear that thing?

Comment: @Md javed Akhtar Has RRL's comment cleared things up for you, or do you need further assistance?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera yes I need further assistance ...The thing I want to know that he told to take the partition in that way I understood that thing but before that he said the choice of tag i want to know that thing clearly that how it is happening can you clear that thing in detail.......And either if you have any other alternative proof pls provide

Answer (score 2):

If you choose tags $\ t_k=-1+\frac{k-1}{n}\ $ for $\ 1\le k\le n\ $ and $\ t_k=\frac{k-n}{n}\ $ for $\ n+1\le k\le 2n-1\ $ with the partitions $\ P_n\ $ given by RRL in his or her comment, then these values of $\ t_i\ $ are admissible (i.e. $\ x_{i-1}\le t_i\le  x_i\ $), and
\begin{align}
S(P_n,f,\alpha)&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}f(t_i)\big(\alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})\big)\\
&=0
\end{align}
because $\ f(t_i)=0\ $ for $\ 1\le k\le n\ $ and $\ \alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})=0\ $ for $\ n+1\le k\le 2n-1\ $.  If you take $\ t_n=\frac{1}{2n} $ instead of $\ t_n={-}\frac{1}{n}\ $, however, and leave all the other values of $\ t_i\ $ the same, then they're still admissible, but now
$$
S(P_n,f,\alpha)=1
$$
because $\ f(t_n)=1\ $ and $\ \alpha(x_n)-\alpha(x_{n-1})=1\ $ while all the other values of $\ f(t_i)\ $ remain the same and none of the values of $\ x_i\ $ have changed.

What's happening here is that $\ n\ $ is the only value of $\ i\ $ for which $\ \alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})\ne0\ $ and when you shift the tag $\ t_n\ $ from the interval $\ \left[{-}\frac{1}{n},0\,\right]\ $ to $\ \left(0,\frac{1}{n}\,\right]\ $ the value of $\ f(t_n)\ $ changes from $\ 0\ $ to $\ 1\ $.